# Is $\nabla_{\left(\frac{\dot\gamma}{\|\dot\gamma\|}\right)}[\,\frac{\dot\gamma}{\|\dot\gamma\|}\,]$ invariant under reparametrization of $\gamma$?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Let $\gamma : [ 0, 1 ] \rightarrow \mathcal M$ and $\sigma : [ 0, 1 ] \rightarrow \mathcal M$ be two [paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)),
such that both have the same image, i.e. the [curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve) $\gamma[ \, [ 0, 1 ] \, ] \equiv \sigma[ \, [ 0, 1 ] \, ] \subset \mathcal M$,
and such that the compositions $\sigma^{(-1)} \circ \gamma : [ 0, 1 ] \rightarrow [ 0, 1 ]$ as well as $\gamma^{(-1)} \circ \sigma : [ 0, 1 ] \rightarrow [ 0, 1 ]$ both exist and are both differentiable.

Thus $\sigma$ is a differentiable reparametrization of $\gamma$, and vice versa.

Is consequently $$ \nabla_{\left(\frac{\dot\gamma}{\|\dot\gamma\|}\right)}\left[\,\frac{\dot\gamma}{\|\dot\gamma\|}\,\right]_{(t \, := \gamma^{(-1)}[ \, P \, ])} = \nabla_{\left(\frac{\dot\sigma}{\|\dot\sigma\|}\right)}\left[\,\frac{\dot\sigma}{\|\dot\sigma\|}\,\right]_{(t \, := \sigma^{(-1)}[ \, P \, ])} := \vec a[ \, P \, ], $$ for any $P \in \mathcal M$, any [affine connection $\nabla$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_connection#Formal_definition_as_a_differential_operator)
and for any (generalized) [norm $\| v \|$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics))$:= \text{sgn}[ \, g[ \, v, v \, ]\, ] \sqrt{ g[ \, v, v\, ] \text{sgn}[ \, g[ \, v, v\, ] \, ] }$
?

Does the value $\vec a[ \, P \, ]$ have an immediate geometric interpretation, perhaps as the product [$(\kappa \, {\mathsf N})_P$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) of curvature $\kappa$ and normal unit vector $\mathsf N$ of curve $\gamma[ \, [ 0, 1 ] \, ]$ at point $P$ ?

Comment: This quantity isn't invariant. Consider a constant-speed path in $\mathbb{R}^n$ versus that same path parametrized with some nonzero acceleration. Thus you can't write $a(P)$ as you have. The interpretation of $\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\dot \gamma$ is the acceleration felt by an observer on the (Riemannian) manifold $M$ whose traversal of the path is given by $\gamma$.

Comment: @Chris: "_Consider a constant-speed path in $\mathbb R^n$ versus that same path parametrized with some nonzero acceleration._" -- If I understand you correctly: $\dot \gamma = const \neq 0$, $\ddot \gamma = 0$ vs. $\ddot \sigma = const \neq 0$. "_Thus you can't write $a(P)$ as you have._" -- The appendage "$... := \vec a[ \, P \, ]$" above is merely supposed to denote the value of the lengthy expression "$\nabla_{()} ...$" under consideration.  "$\vec a[ \, P \, ]$" is **not supposed to stand for** $\ddot \sigma$. Does this help?, or should I edit? ...

Comment: @Chris: "_The interpretation of $\nabla_{\dot \gamma} \dot \gamma$ is the acceleration felt by an observer on the (Riemannian) manifold [...]_" -- Fair enough. The observer's path through a (strictly) Riemannian manifold then involves a particular relevant "time parametrization". However, beyond my concrete OP question, I'm thinking of traversals of (paths in) Lorentzian manifolds, and their invariants wrt. parametrization.

Comment: Sorry about that; I had misread the question. Since you're normalizing the velocity vector, these quantities should be the same. My mistake. As for the interpretation, I'm only familiar with the "acceleration felt by someone walking" on that path. I'm not sure if it carries over to Lorentzian manifolds in the same way.

Comment: @Chris: "_Sorry about that; I had misread the question._" -- Never mind; I'm grateful that your comment gave me a chance at clarification. "_As for the interpretation, I'm only familiar with the "acceleration felt by someone walking" on that path. I'm not sure if it carries over to Lorentzian manifolds in the same way._" -- Accordingly, I've just asked [this question: _Given a trajectory in terms of visited events and Lorentzian distances between these events, how to express its acceleration?_](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3324520).